# Can you use Azure CDN without having to upload the files to Azure storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, cdn

I have a website where I would like to cache the few images/stylesheets/javascript-files I have. Is it possible to have Azure CDN point directly on the files on my server, and then cache them, instead of having to upload them to an Azure storage?

Comment: Is your website hosted in Azure as well?

Comment: @GauravMantri No it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Azure will not allow you to configure arbitrary domain as `origin domain` to support origin content pull. The only available targets are existing `azure website`, `cloudservice` or `storage account`.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

Let us discuss your desired end goal.

If you want to improve your caching with CDN related functionality with the same domain name, take a look at [Cloud Flare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).

However, if you were going to a separate your content into a CDN domain and the application domain, you could look at expanding the following MSDN sample. The idea with this sample is so that as a deployment step, you upload all the CDN related content to the Azure Storage Account.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Synchronizing-Files-to-a14ecf57